# Absolute convergence of power series, true/false?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true? If so, how can I prove it?

> If the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ converges for all $x
>  \in (x_0, x_1)$ then it converges absolutely for all $x \in
>  (-\max\{|x_0|, |x_1|\}, \max\{|x_0|, |x_1|\})$.

Comment: I assume $x_0 = a$ and $x_1 = b$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Opps, typo, made an edit :)

Comment: The general hint for this: "comparison with a geometric series".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is first showing absolute convergence. Once you show that, then for any $y_0 \in (-\max\lbrace |x_0|, |x_1| \rbrace, \max\lbrace |x_0|, |x_1| \rbrace)$, we can find a $y_1 \in (x_0, x_1)$, with $|y_1| > |y_0|$. Then, because of absolute convergence at $y_1$, we can use the comparison test:
$$\sum |a_n| |y_0|^n \le \sum |a_n| |y_1|^n < \infty,$$
so $\sum a_n y_0^n$ converges absolutely.

Now to show absolute convergence. Take an arbitrary $y_0 \in (x_0, x_1)$ and choose $y_1$ in the same interval such that $|y_1| > |y_0|$.  Then, since $\sum a_n y_1^n$ converges, by the divergence test, we must have $a_n y_1^n \rightarrow 0$. It therefore follows that there exists an $N$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies |a_n| |y^n_1| < 1 \implies |a_n| |y^n_0| < \left|\frac{y_0}{y_1}\right|^n.$$
Note that $|y_0/y_1| < 1$, so we have a convergent series, so by the comparison test, $\sum a_n y_0^n$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

All power series are based on this

$$0 <a <b\implies 0 < \frac {a}{b}<1$$

and

$|q|<1\implies  \sum q^n $ converges.

The rest is artistic.

Comment: I wander where did you find out that those numbers are positive...

Comment: @AndréCaldas This is Abel's Lemma.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to what you wrote. I wonder why would someone call such a silly merely artistic "lemma" with a pompous name like "Abel's Lemma". Although I agree that the basis of the arguments *I* *know* is exactly what you worte, I think it is just arrogant to say everything else is "artistic". It is just my silly opinion...

Maybe, your observation is a very nice thing to say to people that already know the answer. In this case, I think it is a very nice observation!!! But I don't really think it answers the OP. Maybe you should just comment instead of posting an answer.